# installing dependencies for the python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, dependencies

I am trying to use a tool which is developed in python 2.7 which is not supported anymore. when I tried to install the dependencies, it did not work for a couple of packages. I even looked for a singularity or Docker image for the too but did not find. do you guys know how I can solve this problem?

Comment: what dependencies are you looking for?

Comment: @Mox: I am trying to install these packages:     PyYAML>=3.11
regex>=2018.01.10
statsmodels>=0.6.1

Comment: have you tried changing >= to ==?